# Given a finite set $X$, which of $\mathcal{P}(X\times X)\times\mathcal{P}(X\times X)$ and $\mathcal{P}({\mathcal{P}(X)})$ has more elements?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, inequality

This is a problem that I found in the book *"Proofs and Fundamentals"*, by E. Bloch.

> **Problem:** Let $X$ be a finite set. Which of the two sets $\mathcal{P}(X \times X) \times \mathcal{P}(X \times X)$ and $\mathcal{P}({\mathcal{P}(X)})$ has more elements?

**Until now:** I already proved that for a finite set $A$ with $a$ elements, $A \times A$ has $a^2$ elements and $\mathcal{P}(A)$ has $2^a$ elements.

So, if $X$ has $n$ elements, then by the same argument, $\mathcal{P}(X \times X) \times \mathcal{P}(X \times X)$ has $2^{2n^2}$ and $\mathcal{P}({\mathcal{P}(X)})$ has $2^{2^n}$.

I'm having trouble with showing which one is greater than the other, I tried induction but I didn't know how to finish. I also tried to see, for what values of $n$, one expression is bigger than the other, but I don't know how to solve that equation.

**The Point:** I would really appreciate if someone could explain how can I deduce which one is greater than the other, and, if possible, to explain other methods that are suitable to solve this problem.

**Thank you very much for your attention**

Comment: Have you tried comparing $2^n$ and $2n^2$?

Comment: I thought of that, but how can I possibly solve an inequality with those expressions??

Comment: Pffff... I don't know. Plug in some values, small and large, formulate an hypothesis, try to prove by induction...

Comment: For "little" $n$ I see that $2n^2$ is bigger, but $2^n$ has an exponential growth. So I guess at some point the latter will be greater than the former. Is there any analytical procedure for finding such $n$??

Comment: Well, find a real number $x$ such that $2x^2=2^x$, then use the fact both functions are increasing at different rates to argue that any integer below $x$ must be "small" and any larger must be "large".

Comment: Finding maxima of $f(x)=2n^2-2^n$ Can be done with derivatives. from there, prove it’s monotone decreasing, I.e. the gap isn’t getting smaller.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you for the suggestion,  I'll try that :)

Comment: @razivo the derivative will be $4n - ln(2) 2^n$ right? So how do I solve the equation to find the roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its true if $n=7$.

So lets try induction with this base case.

From the induction hypothesis we get:

$2^{n+1}=2^n+2^n\geq 2n^2+2n^2$.

OTOH: $2(n+1)^2=2n^2+4n+2$.

So we need: $2n^2\geq 4n+2$.

Again this is true if $n=7$. So try this one by second induction. Here the induction step is easier. If $2n^2\geq 4n+2$ then:

$2(n+1)^2=2n^2+4n+2\geq 4n+2+4n+2\geq 4(n+1)+2$.

Comment: So the base case of the induction is $n=7$. Then we prove for the others values greater than $7$, is that?

Comment: Yes that's right. It might be a good exercise to first do the inequality $2n^2\geq 4n+2$ by induction (one can take a smaller base case here too). Then do your main inequality by induction, with $n=7$ as the base case. (But one doesn't "know" they need the inequality $2n^2\geq 4n+2$ until after messing around with the main inequality.)

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much for the explanation! :)